# Leaflet js fictional map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am new to Leaflet and I would like to find out if how to create a fully interactive fictional map. I have an image that I would like to convert to a leaflet map. This image has a number of connections and points like a graph basically.

I want to first of all convert that image to the map, be able to hover over the points, highlight them and display information about them and also to create animations at some point but not immediately with the connections. There is also a requirement to display permanent labels next to each point.

Is that at all possible in Leaflet?

Comment: Did you ever end up finding a good way to go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is that at all possible in Leaflet?

[Yes](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/questions-with-yes-or-no-answers.html).

Start by reading the [leaflet tutorial for non-geographical maps](http://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html).

Comment: Thanks. That's encouraging

Comment: Any examples out there apart from what you sent me?