# Show a map on a web page as a series of images

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to build a webpage that will allow a user to display a dungeon map from images stored in an array (directly or by reference) to a  block. Suffice to say I am not having a lot of luck and I have researched until I am blue in the face. Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong...

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dungeons and Dragons 3.5 Map Generator</title>
    <script src="GenerateMaps.js"></script>

    <link rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body onload="runExperiments();">
    <div id="row">
        <div class="page_items" id="map">
            <script>
                window.onload=function() {
                    let c = document.getElementById("map");
                    let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
                    let x;
                    let y;
                    c.width = (window.innerWidth / 2)-(window.innerWidth % 30);
                    c.height = (window.innerHeight)-(window.innerHeight % 30);
                    ctx.width = c.width - 30;
                    ctx.height = c.width - 30;
                    let elem = document.createElement("image");
                    elem.setAttribute("src", "floor.png");
                    elem.setAttribute("height", "30");
                    elem.setAttribute("width", "30");
                    elem.setAttribute("src", "floor.png");
                    for (x = 30; x < ctx.height; x += 30) {
                        for (y = 30; y < ctx.width; y += 30) {
                            c.appendChild(elem);
                        }
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Probably worth you having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298791/leaflet-js-fictional-map instead of trying to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

You might have other problems, but the immediate one is highlighted if you look at the Console of the developer tools in your browser.

> Uncaught TypeError: c.getContext is not a function
>       at window.onload

[`getContext`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext) is a function found on [`canvas` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas) but you are trying to call it on a div.

Comment: I managed to solve the initial problem by removing the context but now I'm getting spaces between the div blocks.and dynamically creating a div block for each row of images.